# Need shouldInteractWithURL delegate to be called in a non-selectable UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, url, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I am using `UITextView` to show some text including some clickable names.

`UITextViews` are in chat bubbles so I don't want them to be selectable but I found that the delegate method `shouldInteractWithURL` is called if only the `UITextView` is selectable.

Is there any way that I can make some parts of text clickable with URL behind, while my `UITextView` is not selectable?

Answer (score 0):

Apple documentation of [isSelectable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextview/1618627-isselectable) say:

> This property controls the ability of the user to select content and
>   interact with URLs and text attachments. The default value is true.

So it looks like to handle URLs you have to enable `Selectable`.

If you decide to do that you can do it in code free way
[image]